# Como desabilitar o botão scroll do mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Gostaria de saber como desabilito o botão central do *mouse* que tem o *scroll*?

Não quero tirar o *scroll* apenas o botão do *scroll* do *mouse* que aprece setinha pra direita esquerda cima e baixo quando clica nele, quero desabilitar isso.

Answer (score 8):

Você pode tentar algo assim:

```
$('body').mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.button == 1) return false;
});
```

Note que os navegadores mais antigos talvez não funcionem desta mesma forma. Experimente este código no **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9grqhjq/)**.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode impedir o clique com o botão de scroll, exemplo:

```js
$('body').mousedown(function(e){
    /*button == 0 botão esquerdo do mouse
     *button == 1 botão do meio, ou botão de scroll
     *button == 2 botão direito do mouse
    */
    if(e.button==1){
      alert('Botão desabilitado');
      return false
    }
});
```

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Clique com o botão do scroll</div>
```

Com javascript puro, faça:

```js
document.body.onmousedown = function(e){
    if(e.button == 1) {
      alert('Botão desabilitado');
      return false;
    }
}
```

```css
div{
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
}
```

```html
<div>Clique com o botão de scroll</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda me ajudo muito, deu certinho aqui, obrigado pessoal.